# Anti-Aliasing from Google-VR SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, daydream

I built a lowpoly 3D scene in Unity (use GVR SDK v1.110.0), and then watching on my Pixel phone, the models is full of sawtooth.

Originally I thought it was my model problem, when I create a new empty scene in unity, and then add a cube, then pack on phone to browse, also full of sawtooth (even if I open the 8x Anti-Aliasing!)

I feel the problem comes from the GVR SDK, can anyone answer my question?

p.s. I uploaded a Unity package (including a cube model), and you can use your daydream phone to view it. And I didn't write any code, just finished the basic GVR setup and enable Anti-aliasing, but the sawtooth problem still exists. You can get it in the links below. Thanks.

[Test_Demo_Unity_Pakage](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ixp9MaAeDuVRB5DY-fNqVTj2wH7G-613)

Sorry, I overlooked the visual sense of the picture, and you can see the sawtooth from cube edge in the image below.

**Sawtooth-Cubes**:

[image: Sawtooth-Cubes]

Comment: provide some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: A screenshot of the issue in your question would have been better than uploading the project...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to improve some of the jagged edges I was getting with 8x MSAA in Quality settings and setting use 24-bit depth in Player settings under Daydream/Cardboard.

[image: Like this]